# from GAP to java or C or something

Tags: java

Recently I discovered this alogrithm that pretty much creates all the numbers that are prime and which prefixes are prime.Unfortunatelly for me it's written in GAP,how can I write this code in Java?

```
    DigitsToInt:=function(d)
      return Sum([1..Size(d)],i->10^(Size(d)-i)*d[i]);
    end;;

    NestPrime:=function(d)
     local i,k;
     for i in [1,3,7,9] do
     d:=Concatenation(d,[i]);
     k:=DigitsToInt(d);
     if(IsPrimeInt(k)) then
      Print(k,"\n");
      NestPrime(d);
    fi;
     d:=List([1..Size(d)-1],j->d[j]);
    od;
    end;;

    for d in [[2],[3],[5],[7]] do
     k:=DigitsToInt(d);
     Print(k,"\n");
     NestPrime(d);
    od;
```

Comment: code conversion is off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: at least can you please explain the alogrithm ?